# Set font type in duplicate layout

Tags: android, view, fonts

I have layount who include one layout, duplicate two time ("include"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonNiebieski">

    <!-- LAYOUT GRACZ (A) -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:scaleY="-1"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/lay1"
            layout="@layout/layout_pojedynek_duplikat" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleY="-1"
            android:scaleX="-1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_gracz_A_liczba_punktow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_gracz_B_liczba_punktow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/lay2"
                layout="@layout/layout_pojedynek_duplikat" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### layout_pojedynek_duplikat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:background="#00ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="POLSKA"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1.0">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1.0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_pojedynek_wariant_A"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:src="@drawable/argentyna"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_pojedynek_wariant_B"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:src="@drawable/kambodza"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1.0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_pojedynek_wariant_C"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:src="@drawable/watykan"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_pojedynek_wariant_D"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:src="@drawable/polska"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In java file I try set font for txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa text field:

```
TextView txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa);
txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa.setTypeface(myFontBold);
```

But this set font for only one view:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

DO that for every view.  Or create a new View class that's a child of TextView and sets the font, and use that instead of TextView.

Yes, Android's font handling sucks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Activity.findViewById()`, the system will traverse your view hierarchy starting from the root until it finds a view with the given id. In other words, `Activity.findViewById()` will return the **first** view with that id in your layout. It will **not** return **all** views with that id.

For this reason, it is generally advised to not re-use ids within a single layout. However, this advice is often not practical, and you shouldn't feel bad about your current layout. But it does mean that you will need to call `TextView.setTypeface()` twice, and that you will need some way to access the **second** view with the id `txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa`.

You can do this by limiting the scope you search with `findViewById()`. Instead of using `Activity.findViewById()`, instead use `View.findViewById()`. So you could write something like this:

```
View lay1 = findViewById(R.id.lay1);
TextView txt1 = (TextView) lay1.findViewById(R.id.txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa);
txt1.setTypeface(myFontBold);

View lay2 = findViewById(R.id.lay2);
TextView txt2 = (TextView) lay2.findViewById(R.id.txt_gracz_A_i_B_nazwa);
txt2.setTypeface(myFontBold);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth answer. Beautiful things work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small logic flaw. The problem with reusing the same layout two times, is that you have the identical IDs although they represent two entirely different UI elements.

lay1.findViewById(your_text_field_id).setFontType
lay2.findViewById(your_text_field_id).setFontType

Should fix you. You can't use generic findViewById as it will grab the first one and use it. Hope that helps.